# Why the imported package (python) doesn't contain its modules (which can be imported without problems)?

Tags: python, import

- I try import from my own code, inside my project.
- I have `__init__.py` everywhere.
- I have removed `__pycache__/` folders (because I have changed views_api.py module into package).
- Python 3.7.11

Now, when I import the package, its modules aren't inside.
But I can import them directly without any problem.
Can someone explain it more, please?

```
from django.urls import path
# from . import views_api     # the package is imported but lacks its submodules
from .views_api import model

urlpatterns = [
    # path('model', views_api.model.VueModelView.as_view()),  # doesn't work
    path('model', model.VueModelView.as_view()),              # works
]
```

Comment: just try to see from execution path how you are importing packages, also it's better to drop `from . import ` just write `import views_api` and python will look in sub directory level first

Comment: `import views_api` results to `No module named 'views_api'`. I don't know what 'from execution path' means, but at that time `sys.path` is: `['/home/mirek/dj/rian/isms', '/home/mirek/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python37.zip', '/home/mirek/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7', '/home/mirek/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/mirek/.local/share/pypoetry/virtualenvs/rian--Fu_jDgC-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']`. The problem is in django's included (ie. applications) urls.py.

Comment: execution path is the `.py` which you are using to start the djano application

Comment: @sahasrara62 > Do you think manage.py? It contains something "how I import packages"?

Comment: [python package import](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_packages.php)  [python import system documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) these are few example which will help you how import works, how it search for packages and how one should use them relative or in absolute way